# Training and testing ML from two different sources

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn` for a classification task. I want to train my model on data from table "train" and test it on data from a different table"test". Both tables have the same exact features, but different numbers of rows. I have the code below, but I am getting the error: 
`(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [123, 174]',), <traceback object at 0x0000016476E10C48>).`

what am I doing wrong?

```py
get_train_data = 'select * from train;'  
get_test_data = 'select * from test;'
df_train = pd.read_sql_query(get_train_data, con=connection)  
df_test = pd.read_sql_query(get_test_data, con=connection)
X = df_train[:, 2:30]
Y = df_test[:, :30]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
split_mat=confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to train on dataframe `df_train` and test on dataframe `df_test`, why are you taking the features of `df_train` and the target column of `df_test` and pass them to the `train_test_split` function?

You can simply do the following:

```py
get_train_data = 'select * from train;' 
get_test_data = 'select * from test;'

df_train = pd.read_sql_query(get_train_data, con=connection)  
df_test = pd.read_sql_query(get_test_data, con=connection)

X_train = df_train[:, 2:30]
y_train = df_train.y # assuming y is the name of your target variable in df_train

X_test = df_test[:, i:j] # change i to j with the number that allow you to take the same columns as X_train
y_test = df_test.y # assuming y is the name of your target variable in df_test

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Do something with predictions, e.g.
mean(predictions == y_test)
```